# WPF How to load large set of data in Listview without any performance issue

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, mvvm, data-binding

I'm fetching a large set of data and binding it with the `Listview`. The whole process takes **3-4 minutes**. I'd like to know the best practice of using MVVM with a large set of data so, I could easily load the data with UI in chunks (let's say 30 sets of items everytime user scroll down) without having any performance issue.

Comment: Best practice is "do not bind item controls with large collections". Are you sure, that some sort of paged list doesn't fit? Also, what takes 3-4 minutes: retrieving data from some external source (web service, database, etc) or rendering of large data source in list view? Could you post relevant code?

Comment: What would you suggest then if item control isn't the solution? Because the application we're working on need to have a listview to display data in a nice manner. But it is taking too much time. Any solution?

Comment: First of all, It's not clear, where does your problem reside - is it data loading issue, or binding/rendering issue. Second - user don't need thousands or millions of list items. It just can't see all these items at time, because visible part of list is usually much smaller. You can implement paging, for example, and bind small chunks of big data list to list view.